# CodeFirst в ASP.NET Core 2.1 с заполненными таблицами

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Собственно из этой статьи [Миграции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/migrations?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) я выяснил, что для того что бы использовать метод `CodeFirst` необходимо применять миграции, однако применять только на новом проекте, т.к таблицы баз данных удаляются и создаются снова. А как применять `CodeFirst` на рабочем проекте в котором уже есть заполненные таблицы, если нужно нарастить функционал приложения?

Comment: Вообще-то, миграции можно [добавить](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database) в любой момент и к уже существующей базе. Таблицы не удаляются сами по себе: что вы сделаете в миграции, то и произойдёт. Это может быть как удаление таблицы, так и добавление колонки, и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала построить модель на основе существующей БД. А потом апгрейдить ее уже через Миграции. [Начало работы с EF Core в ASP.NET Core с существующей базой данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

Comment: Ваша ссылка как раз таки рассказывает о методе databaseFirst, когда уже есть созданная база данных и через -Scaffold можно автоматически создать классы. @Alexander Petrov был прав, осталось до конца понять суть миграции.